# Surround Embedded Coffeescript in ECO in VIM

Tags: vim, coffeescript, eco

Are there any shortcuts to surround embedded Coffeescript (in eco templates) in VIM?

`<%= @something %>`

Whether in insert mode or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin can do this. You will have to set up a custom replacement to do this. One of the examples in the surround help file actually does exactly what you want. The example says to add the line

```
let g:surround_61 = "<%= \r %>"
```

to your `.vimrc`.

In this the `\r` is the  placeholder for whatever text you are surrounding and the `61` in the variable name means that ASCII character 61 will be the shortcut for this surround, which is `=`. To use this you then use one of surround's bindings and type `=` as the surround character. For example the command `ysiW=` would surround the current word with `<%= ... %>`. The `ys` part is the key binding to add surrounding text. `iW` is the motion that will be surrounded (it represents "inside word") and then `=` is the surround to use, which here is set up to be a custom surround.

Comment: For readability sake, I tend to write my surround variables like so: `let g:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= echo \r %>"`. You may also want to do this for only buffers with eco filetypes. I would suggest you create a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/eco.vim` and use: `let b:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= echo \r %>"`. The `b:var` will make the variable local to the buffer not global.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an additional alternative that I discovered later using snipMate. I could add a `eco.snippets` file to the snippets directory containing:

```
snippet =
    <%= ${1} %>
```

Took care of it to where I could just type `=` and then `tab` it into existence.